# Painting over a shattered miror

Tags: repair, painting, adhesive, mirror

I recently shattered a sliding mirror/door in my entrance, it's about 250x130cm, so replacing it is not financially wise, and painting over it would look nice anyway, bringing my to my question : how should i go around with it?
To keep the thickness of the door I'm considering putting wall liner on it, which would also reinforce the cracks in the mirror. My problem is that i'm unsure as to wether the glue would stick to a mirror, most of them listing rougher textures, nothing as smooth as glass or mirror. Is there any kind of resin that i should put as a first layer?

[image]

[image]

I did my best to translate the "technical" terms i know to english, if anything doesn't make sense, or you just want more details, feel free to ask for clarification ;)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: With no pictures to tell how bad it is cracked, I would remove the mirror pieces carefully and replace with wood/plywood.  Don't take a chance of the glass falling out, maybe on a kid.

Comment: Give us a pic of what you have to work with...

Comment: Pictures are added.
The mirror being quite thick, removing it would indeed imply having to replace it with wood/plywood, but as it is, it feels "sturdy" enough to last, should it be held via a front liner

Comment: Covering glass to a point where no one knows it is there seems like a really bad idea. I think it would be better to remove the glass or simply remove the door if funds are an issue to do any sort of replacement

Comment: Honestly, I'd get a couple (maybe you can get by with one) sheets of MDF or similar and replace the glass.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what wall liner represents, but one could consider to use decorative self-adhesive vinyl sheeting. My search has found various types of this product. Being self-adhesive means that the flat surface of the glass would provide good bonding. The widest I found is 160 cm by 40 cm which means you'd have to take care to align the edges for best results. There may be wider product available and some of them of great lengths are only 30 cm, which means a compromise of sorts.

The cracks would also be visible through the vinyl, although using filler and sanding the surface flush would mitigate this. To provide additional security, wrap the vinyl around the edges and bottom and secure to the back side.

It's likely the vinyl will be of minimal thickness, well under a millimeter and would abrade from any substantial contact.

One product on Amazon is [Premium Self-Adhesive Leather Repair Patch - 16x158 Inches, Waterproof & Durable Leather Repair Tape](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C8B5YT1W) available in two lengths, but still vinyl and subject to wear, of course. Image below from linked site.

There are plenty of other similar options, including many colors and patterns. Some of the more unusual patterns resemble snowflakes or fractal designs. There may be something to match your preferences.

[image: leather-like vinyl patch material]

Comment: Wall liner were the products that seemed to fit best on english online shops, in french we call it "toile de verre" which translates to glass cloth, a sheet of glass fiber that is usually used on walls to even them out, and can be painted over, works sort of as wallpaper, and comes in large rolls
As i already have paint that matches my walls (leftovers), it's my prefered option at the moment (and the sheet+glue come quite cheep considering the size)